# Preload can't find field fieldName in *models.Catalog

Tags: go, go-gorm

I can't find an answer to my question. I am using jinzhu/gorm in a golang project:)
I have the following structs:

```
type Catalog struct {
    ID              int64       `gorm:"primary_key" form:"id"`
    SubDomainID     int64       `form:"sub_domain_id"`
    ServiceTypeID   int64       `form:"service_type_id"`
    Checked         bool        `form:"checked"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time   `form:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt       time.Time   `form:"updated_at"`

    SubDomain       SubDomain
}

type SubDomain struct {
   Id       int64   `gorm:"primary_key" form:"id"`
   NameRu   string  `form:name_ru`
   url  string  `form:url`
}
```

When I try to get catalog with preloading of subdomain:

```
var catalog Catalog
fmt.Println(catalog.SubDomain)
err := db.Preload("SubDomain").Where("checked = 0").First(&catalog).Error
if err != nil {
    return &catalog, err
}
```

I get the following error: `can't find field SubDomain in *models.Catalog`

Why is this happening?

I expect there will be 2 queries:

1. select * from catalogs where checked = 0;
2. select * from sub_domains where id = (catalog.sub_domain_id)

Comment: Here is the line creating that error in the library : https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/9982134955389352ef19c1bcf0a3a8324bb4d2b2/preload.go#L78

Comment: Yeah, in for before that if range currentFields. So it's really not contain SubDomain... Don't know why...

Comment: The problem is probably on the `field.Relationship == nil` part. I'm not sure how gorm identifies a relationship, the code isn't really documented

Comment: Nope, don't know why, but in this for currentFields do not contain SubDomain field. It has another fields, but not SubDomain struc. So, in this for (field.Name != key) == true

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to gorm, but I think I know your problem and also have a (partial) solution.
As stated before (and you said so yourself), when applying "select * from..." it also looks for the field SubDomain (because it is in your struct).
So I believe this should work:

```
var catalog Catalog
fmt.Println(catalog.SubDomain)
err := db.Preload("SubDomain").Select("ID","SubDomainID", "ServiceTypeID").Where("checked = 0").First(&catalog).Error
if err != nil {
    return &catalog, err
}
```

note how i specified the exact fields. A better solution will be to write a function to exclude member which are fields, using reflection. I am using a similar solution myself. it kinda looks like this:

```
for each member of Domain:
    if member is string or boolean
        fields.append(member).
return db.Select(fields) // actual gormdb's Select
```